# mark table row using HTML5 local storage

Tags: jquery, html

We are trying to write a code to mark table rows using html5 local storage and jquery. Please check following code...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table tbody tr').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        localStorage.setItem( "row", id );
    });
});
```

we want to apply yellow bg color to table row if that id is in local storage, can you please help us to write this code? thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set an item in local storage:

```
localStorage.setItem('key', 'some value');
```

To read an item from local storage:

```
var value = localStorage.getItem('key');
```

To apply yellow background color to the DOM element using jquery:

```
$(this).css({ backgroundColor: 'Yellow' });
```

Comment: but how to check if id is local storage and if yes put yellow bg.

Comment: @seoppc, this will depend under which key you have stored it. So for example you could store an array of ids in local storage: `localStorage.setItem('ids', [ '4', '7', '9' ]);` and then fetch this array back: `var ids = localStorage.getItem('ids');` and check whether the current `id` is in this array using the [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method and if it is apply the corresponding color.

Comment: @seoppc, I can't provide any code without knowing what you are trying to achieve. So far you have only said that you wanted to apply yellow background color to a table row if its corresponding id was in local storage. But you said nothing about how those ids were added to the local storage, under what event/circumstances/form, etc... Things that you need to clarify before we get to any specific code.

Comment: we have data table and i a star icon like gmail, we would like to highlight that row if somebody clicks star icon, and it should be highlighted(using html5 local storage help), and if user clicks star again it should remove highlight, i hope it makes sense. thanks.